# How do I install Cppcheck using the tar file on Linux?

Tags: linux, installation, cppcheck

I'm trying to install Cppcheck via telnet on a Linux box. I have the cppcheck-1.67.tar file and I untar it. I don't see anything that will install it for me. Am I approaching this the correct way?

Comment: This would probably be a better fit for the unix stackexchange.

Answer (score 8):

**Actual on a date publication of this answer.**

1. Download file from there https://sourceforge.net/projects/cppcheck/
2. Go to the folder with for downloads

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads/
   ```
3. Unpack archive

   ```
   tar -xvf cppcheck-1.76.1.tar.bz2
   ```
4. Go to unpacked folder

   ```
   cd cppcheck-1.76.1/
   ```
5. Install package as root

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```
6. Check up result

   ```
   $ which cppcheck
   /usr/bin/cppcheck
   ```
7. Testing it

   ```
   $ touch simple.c
   $ echo "int main(){ int a; a + 1; return 0}" > simple.c
   $ cppcheck simple.c
   Checking simple.c ...
   [simple.c:1]: (error) Uninitialized variable: a
   ```

This package also exists in a standard repository.

```
$ aptitude search cppcheck
p   cppcheck                      - tool for static C/C++ code analysis
```

Testing environment

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:    Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:    jessie
$ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"Actual on a date publication of this answer"*?

Answer (score 2):

The instructions are in the `readme.txt` file. The short answer is `make install`.

Remember never to install things from a tar file when you can use your distribution's package manager.

Comment: Unless your distribution lags

Answer (score 1):

The readme.txt file makes no mention of "make install".

It looks like the supplied Makefile is borked:

1. It passes "CFG=" param to compile, without DESTDIR
2. But "make install" prepends DESTDIR to CFGDIR

In my case, I edited Makefile to remove DESTDIR from make install, and cppcheck is happy with that.

Answer (score 1):

For me the magic lines turned out to be the following in Docker on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver):

```
RUN cd /tmp \
    && git clone https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck.git \
    && cd cppcheck \
    && git checkout 1.72 \
    && make SRCDIR=build CFGDIR=/usr/bin/cfg HAVE_RULES=yes install \
    && cd /tmp \
    && rm -rf /tmp/cppcheck \
    && ldconfig
```

I assume the following will work for any version. I am not sure where it makes sense to install the configuration to. This works for me:

```
make SRCDIR=build CFGDIR=/usr/bin/cfg HAVE_RULES=yes install
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a later version than in the other answers, and you want to install it, then you can use the bash script below which is up to date and builds on the other answers. It should also clean itself up afterwards. It works for version 2.7 on debian/ubuntu but you can change the git checkout tag and try your luck on newer versions.

installcppcheck.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck.git
cd cppcheck 
git checkout 2.7 
make MATCHCOMPILER=yes FILESDIR=/usr/share/cppcheck HAVE_RULES=yes CXXFLAGS="-O2 -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-function" install
cd /tmp
rm -rf /tmp/cppcheck
ldconfig
cppcheck --version
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `sudo` privileges you can follow @Seti Volkylany's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41180209/1938859), replacing step 5 with

```sh
OUT_PATH=/home/user/bin  # target location of binary
make SRCDIR=build CFGDIR=~/Downloads/cppcheck-1.76.1/cfg PREFIX=$OUT_PATH
make install CFGDIR=$OUT_PATH/cppcheck-1.76.1/cfg PREFIX=$OUT_PATH
```